# LDS + VF page doing unexpected behavior on adding a <apex:form> tag

Tags: visualforce, lightning, html, css, lightning-design-system

I am using LDS + VF pages to make a simple calculator. Pressing a button at the bottom will set a flag in the controller and that flag will `render` an element and un-`render` another. For rendering, I NEED `<apex:form>` tag.

**EDIT : ** [Button code is here...](http://codepad.org/xFGMNT3N)

As you can see, pretty simple work.

I am using LDS + CSS to style the buttons (CSS file in a static resource).

I have a `<div class="slds-grid">` that holds three (3) `<div class="slds-col">`.

Inside each `sdls-col` there are custom buttons styled via CSS. Clicking them changes a `<div>` via `document.getElementById("Display_Div_Id");`.

When I add `<apex:form>` tags ANYWHERE in the page, the FIRST and SECOND `slds-col` and its buttons behave VERY weird.

They change the `Display_Div_Id` AND refresh the page. This is ESPECIALLY weird since the buttons in the third `slds-col` are very simple/dummy/mockup buttons with NO code/logic.

They should not even be changing ANYTHING.

What I require :

1. Why the page is behaving weird.
2. A way to `render` elements without using `<apex:form>`

As always, thanks for reading. (pls dont edit, im trying to be polite to ppl who spend their time to help me)

Comment: Can you add the button mark up ? Thanks

Comment: Yes ofc, you will have to wait, though, I will take a few minutes and add it to the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are adding apex:form ,the button by default is rendering of type=submit .Use the Type attribute to specify its just of type of button .

Change your button code to below

```
<button id="lightbluebutton5" type="button" onclick="show_amt_leftbutton(10)" style="height:65px" class="button slds-size--3-of-5">10</button>
```

Notice how i have added an attribute to explicitly mention that it is of type=button to avoid submit of the form by default .

Comment: OH!!! Now I understand what was going wrong (my "buttons" in the 2nd column were just divs with an onclick attribute :) )! Thank you! Just perfect!